# In PowerBI, Is it possible to conditionally format sparkline columns (not lines)?

Tags: conditional-formatting, powerbi-custom-visuals, sparklines

I'm presenting % change of price by week and would like negative % change bars to be red and positive % change bars to be green.  Right now, I can only choose one color for all.  I've come across some posts relating to SVG code for lines, but I didn't have any success applying it to my use case.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]